# Inorder traversal of expression tree in java

Tags: java, tree, expression, inorder

I am creating inorder traversal of expression tree but it is not considering the middle element. Below is my code. Can you please let me know where i am wroong and code i have missed.
e.g if the prefix notation of expression tree is  * 1 + 2 3 then the output of inorder tree along with paranthesis should be (1+(2*3)) but i am getting output (1(23)+)*

```
public String toStringPrettyInFix(){

    return printInorder(root)+")";

}

String printInorder(FCNSTreeNode root)
{

    String s="";
    if (root == null)
        return "";

    if(root.firstChild!=null) {


        s=s+"("+printInorder(root.firstChild);

    }     



    if(root.nextSibling!=null) {
        s=s+printInorder(root.nextSibling)+")";

    }


System.out.println(s);

    return s;

}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To your question - you do not append the "middle element", this is why it is not considered. Somewhere between `if(root.firstChild!=null) { ... }` and `if(root.nextSibling!=null) { ... }` you should handle `root.middleElement` or whatever it is called.

Answer (score 1):

In order traverse left then visit middle then go right.Here you missed the middle part

```
if(root.firstChild!=null) {


    s=s+"("+printInorder(root.firstChild);

}     

s = s+root.value //value is whatever stored in node 

if(root.nextSibling!=null) {
    s=s+printInorder(root.nextSibling)+")";

}
```